# Multiple solutions for quadratic equation condition.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

**Q.** All the values of m for which both roots of the equations $x^2-2mx+m^2-1=0$ are 
greater than −2 but less than 4, lie in the interval.

Well I have done this by taking the roots,lets say,

(**$\alpha $**,**$\beta $**) = $\frac{\left(2m\pm \:\sqrt{4m^2-4\left(m^2-1\right)}\right)}{2}=\left(m\pm \:1\right)$

which gives

$-2<\left(m\pm \:1\right)<-4$ which gives

$-1<m<3$.

**But I have seen another solution in my text which goes like:**

$-4<\alpha +\beta <8$ which gives $-4<2m<8$ (as $-\frac{b}{a}=2m$)

which gives $-2<m<4$.

**From trusted sites I have found that my method is correct. But the second method doesn't seem wrong. How is that?**

Answer (score 0):

The solution give by your text is incomplete (or wrong). If the roots lie in the interval $(-2,4)$ then the sum of the roots will lie in $(-4,8)$. However the converse is not true and that is where the text solution has made an error. For example, take $m=7/2$. Then the sum of the roots will still lie in the interval mentioned above, whereas one of the roots will be greater than $4$.

Comment: I didn't get that. There's nothing wrong in one of roots being greater than four here the value of 'm' is the one which should not exceed 4. And if m=7/2 that gives -4<7<8 which is correct.

Comment: If you read the question carefully it says find those $m$ for which BOTH roots lie in $(-2,4)$. For $m=7/2$, which lies in the textbook interval but NOT in your interval, one of the roots is greater than $4$, hence this value of $m$ is incorrect. This means the textbook solution is incorrect.

Comment: If my interpretation of the question is incorrect then please revise your question because it seems to be incomplete.